# Heroku sign up and customer's support

Tags: heroku

I have been trying to sign up into Heroku website but it keeps bringing issues that there is a problem signing up, I couldn't find any means to lay complain to there customer's support because I have to login first. Can someone provide me a solution on how to go about it or can provide me with another web hosting site that I can use to host Django web app.
Thanks

I tried to sign up on heroku but it keeps telling me there trouble signing up, i tried to contact there customer care but i could not because i must have an account before i can have access to there customer

Comment: Hey let me know if you found a solution to this. I still am facing the same issue. Although I did find a fix. It'll let you sign up with an workspace mail that is for example.                             olufisayo.o@company-name.com